# Is there a test for statistical significance if I'm comparing two different groups in terms of the percentage with a particular characteristic?

Tags: statistical-significance, spss

I'm not sure if it's possible without having the underlying dataset. I don't have that, but I do know the numbers of people in each group (i.e., the sample size).

Comment: If all you have is the sample size, you can't determine *anything.*  Could you tell us everything you *do* have rather than what you *don't* have?

Comment: I literally just have a series of percentage figures for the two groups, covering a range of dimensions. So all I can do is see whether and how big the gap is between the two groups.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "percentage figure" and "range of dimensions." These terms don't have a commonly understood meaning and so are likely to be *misunderstood* in the absence of a specific definition or description.

Comment: As in I have two groups, and X percent of each fall within a particular category. The data is from a survey with multiple questions.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have 55.2% in favor out of 223 subjects in Group 1
and 62.5% in favor out of 456 subjects in Group 2.
Then you have 123 in favor in Group 1
and 285 in favor in Group 2.

In R, the procedure `prop.test` can test whether the two
proportions in favor differ significantly at the 5% level.
The result is that the proportions in favor, although
somewhat different, are significant at the 7% level of
significance but not at the 5% level, on account of the
P-value $0.06651.$  [Continuity correction is not
used because of the relatively large sample sizes.]

```
prop.test(c(123,285), c(223, 456), cor=F)

    2-sample test for equality of proportions 
    without continuity correction

data:  c(123, 285) out of c(223, 456)
X-squared = 3.3672, df = 1, p-value = 0.06651
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.152393715  0.005532729
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2 
0.5515695 0.6250000
```

This test is essentially equivalent to doing a chi-squared
test on a $2 \times 2$ table, with rows for Yes and No
and columns for Gp1 and Gp2, as follows.

```
yes = c(123, 285)
tot = c(223, 456)
no = tot - yes
TBL = rbind(yes, no); TBL
    [,1] [,2]
yes  123  285
no   100  171

chisq.test(TBL, cor=F)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TBL
X-squared = 3.3672, df = 1, p-value = 0.06651
```

*Notes:* (1) By contrast, if you have 123 in 1000
in Group 1 and 285 in 1000 in Group 2, then the
proportions are clearly significantly different;
`prop.test` gives a P-value near $0,$ so that
proportions are different below the 1% level.

```
prop.test(c(123,285), c(1000, 1000), cor=F)

        2-sample test for equality of proportions 
        without continuity correction

data:  c(123, 285) out of c(1000, 1000)
X-squared = 80.808, df = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.1966002 -0.1273998
sample estimates:
 prop 1 prop 2 
  0.123  0.285
```

(2) If this is not exactly what you're looking for, please look at the links under 'Related' in
the margin of this page to see if something there
is helpful.